# Multiple pipes in C

Tags: c, exec, fork, pipe, dup2

I want to implement multi pipes in c so I can do something like this, where `|||` means duplicate the stdin to N pipe commands):

`cat /tmp/test.log ||| wc -l ||| grep test1 ||| grep test2 | grep test3`

This will return to me the number of lines in the file **and** the lines in the file that contain 'test1' string **and** the lines in the file that contain 'test2' && 'test3' string

In other words this would have the effect of these 3 regular pipelines:

```
cat /tmp/test.log  | wc -l --> stdout
                   | grep test1 --> stdout
                   | grep test2 | grep test3 --> stdout
```

Has someone already implementated something like this? I didn't find anything...
NOTE: I know it can be done with scripting languages or with bash multiple file descriptors, but I am searching C code to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the '||' operator means 'logical or' in the shell, i.e. false || echo hi results in 'hi'.

Comment: What you are after is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780943/duplicate-file-descriptor-after-popen); the answer there should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your should start off with the `tee` command and [examine their code](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/bsd/bsd-current/tee/tee.c).

Comment: You could also look at the source to bash and determine how it performs the similar piping function.  Nothing of your description explicitly states that the order of finishing and output collation was important; you'll have to take care of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is impossible in C to have more than one process (or thread) read the same file descriptor *without draining the data read*, all solutions will have to store the data read in a temporary file and then each read the temp file.